# T-SQL JOIN/WHERE IN returning different results

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a query that I'm trying to optimize as best I can, and it'd help me a lot if I could use a join instead of what it currently is (a WHERE IN).

Currently, my query is:

```
SELECT  
cus.*
, com.COM_ID
, cha.CHA_NAME
FROM thing.dbo.VIEW_REPORT cus --View
LEFT JOIN otherthing.dbo.TBL_COMMUNICATION com 
ON com.REC_ID = cus.REC_ID 
AND com.RUN_ID = cus.RUN_ID 
LEFT JOIN otherthing.dbo.TBL_CHANNEL cha
ON cha.CHA_ID = com.CHA_ID 
WHERE com.COM_ID in (
    SELECT eve.COM_ID 
    FROM otherthing.dbo.TBL_EVENT eve)
```

I'm trying to optimise this by joining to TBL_EVENT rather than a WHERE IN (I believe I read they run the same way, but I'd also like to select some TBL_EVENT columns so it'd be nice to join). My new query is something like this:

```
SELECT  
cus.*
, com.COM_ID
, cha.CHA_NAME
FROM thing.dbo.VIEW_REPORT cus --View
LEFT JOIN otherthing.dbo.TBL_COMMUNICATION com 
ON com.REC_ID = cus.REC_ID 
AND com.RUN_ID = cus.RUN_ID 
LEFT JOIN otherthing.dbo.TBL_CHANNEL cha
ON cha.CHA_ID = com.CHA_ID 
INNER JOIN otherthing.dbo.TBL_EVENT eve
ON com.COM_ID = eve.COM_ID
```

I figured using an Inner Join would mean that it'd only return results that are in both TBL_COMMUNICATION and TBL_EVENT. **And this is where things get weird.**

The original query (at the top) returns ~200,000 records. My new query returns around ~1,100,000 records. But from my perspective they're the same query, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've moved the INNER JOIN to TBL_EVENT above the other left joins, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Can anyone tell me what I should be doing to return the same data by joining to TBL_EVENT?

Comment: When `left join`, put the right side table's conditions in the `ON` clause to get true left join behavior. (When in WHERE, you get regular inner join result.)

Comment: If there are *3* records with COM_ID = 'Z' in `table 1`, and *4* records in `table 2` with COM_ID = 'Z', the result will be 3 x 4 records = *12* records. Is COM_ID unique in either table?

Comment: COM_ID is unique in TBL_COMMUNICATION. I realise what you're saying so I'm just trying a SELECT DISTINCT now, which theoretically should return the same amount. (That is, the correct amount)

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` has its own performance issues though.

Comment: `WHERE EXISTS` _might_ perform better but it doesn't let you return a column from `TBL_EVENT`

Comment: I see - it's taking a lot longer. Any other suggestions? It took an extra 30 seconds or so but returned the same amount as the first query.

Comment: I'll save way more performance if I can select columns from TBL_EVENT as I actually do way more in the query further on (not posted here), so I may have to stick with the SELECT DISTINCT. It's not a whole lot worse.

Comment: You could try wrapping up just the `TBL_EVENT` part in a select distinct:  `INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT COL1, COM_ID FROM otherthing.dbo.TBL_EVENT) eve ON com.COM_ID = eve.COM_ID` rather than the whole lot. Make sure you use CTRL-L against all of these queries and see if any indexes are suggested. Do you have any indexing options?

Comment: All of the join columns are indexed already. From what I can tell (and it may just be super cached now) there's next to no performance benefits haha. I'll try again in a bit when the server clears the cache, but I think the SELECT DISTINCT works best. Do you want to add your answer officially and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 2):

They are not the same

```
WHERE com.COM_ID in (
   SELECT eve.COM_ID 
   FROM otherthing.dbo.TBL_EVENT eve)
```

Says that com.COM_ID has to be found in the result of the subquery. But

```
INNER JOIN otherthing.dbo.TBL_EVENT eve
   ON com.COM_ID = eve.COM_ID
```

says to join in all posts where eve.COM_ID is the same as com.COM_ID.

If you have more than one post with the same COM_ID in eve.COM_ID you will get multiple posts in your result.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is weird here, that happens when there are more than 1 row in TBL_EVENT match with 1 row of joining of VIEW_REPORT and TBL_COMMUNICATION.

You cannot optimise like your second script to get same result first

Instead of reusing your first, you can optimise sql like below, that will improve speed of your script

```
SELECT  
cus.*
, com.COM_ID
, cha.CHA_NAME
FROM thing.dbo.VIEW_REPORT cus --View
LEFT JOIN otherthing.dbo.TBL_COMMUNICATION com 
ON com.REC_ID = cus.REC_ID 
AND com.RUN_ID = cus.RUN_ID 
and com.COM_ID in (
    SELECT distinct eve.COM_ID 
    FROM otherthing.dbo.TBL_EVENT eve)
LEFT JOIN otherthing.dbo.TBL_CHANNEL cha
ON cha.CHA_ID = com.CHA_ID 
INNER JOIN otherthing.dbo.TBL_EVENT eve
ON com.COM_ID = eve.COM_ID
```

or

```
SELECT  
cus.*
, com.COM_ID
, cha.CHA_NAME
FROM thing.dbo.VIEW_REPORT cus --View
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM otherthing.dbo.TBL_COMMUNICATION com WHERE com.COM_ID IN (SELECT distinct eve.COM_ID FROM otherthing.dbo.TBL_EVENT eve)) com 
ON com.REC_ID = cus.REC_ID 
AND com.RUN_ID = cus.RUN_ID 
LEFT JOIN otherthing.dbo.TBL_CHANNEL cha
ON cha.CHA_ID = com.CHA_ID
```

Comment: There are literally hundreds of millions of records in TBL_EVENT (and several million in TBL_COMMUNICATION) so I'm kind of thinking joins would be better?

Answer (score 0):

You were killing the LEFT JOIN otherthing.dbo.TBL_COMMUNICATION com with the where so this will give you another answer.  If you like your first answer better then change that to a regular join.

```
SELECT cus.*, com.COM_ID, cha.CHA_NAME
FROM thing.dbo.VIEW_REPORT cus --View
LEFT JOIN otherthing.dbo.TBL_COMMUNICATION com 
       ON com.REC_ID = cus.REC_ID 
      AND com.RUN_ID = cus.RUN_ID 
      AND exists ( SELECT 1 
                   FROM otherthing.dbo.TBL_EVENT eve 
                   where eve.COM_ID = com.COM_ID )
LEFT JOIN otherthing.dbo.TBL_CHANNEL cha
       ON cha.CHA_ID = com.CHA_ID
```

But that query just does not make sense to me.
Why would you restrict the right side of a left join?
Pretty sure you mean for that to be an inner join.

```
SELECT cus.*, com.COM_ID, cha.CHA_NAME
FROM thing.dbo.VIEW_REPORT cus --View
JOIN otherthing.dbo.TBL_COMMUNICATION com 
       ON com.REC_ID = cus.REC_ID 
      AND com.RUN_ID = cus.RUN_ID 
      AND exists ( SELECT 1 
                   FROM otherthing.dbo.TBL_EVENT eve 
                   where eve.COM_ID = com.COM_ID )
LEFT JOIN otherthing.dbo.TBL_CHANNEL cha
       ON cha.CHA_ID = com.CHA_ID
```

post the query plan